# Binding Soap request body to C# in .NET Core

Tags: xml, wcf, .net-core, soap, blazor

I have the following SOAP request body. I need C# class to bind the data:

[image]

I have following c# classes but it does not work:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Brand")]
public class Brand
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DatiPratica")]
[XmlType(TypeName = "ElementiDatiPratica", Namespace = "http://crogwebnew.satoprg.net/soap")]
public class DatiPratica
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Brand")]
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soap", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Soap { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RichiestaFin", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
public class RichiestaFin
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DatiPratica")]
    public DatiPratica DatiPratica { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "encodingStyle", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public string EncodingStyle { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Body
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RichiestaFin", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
    public RichiestaFin RichiestaFin { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public string Header { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsd { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soapenv", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Soapenv { get; set; }

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    public Envelope()
    {
        ns.Add("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        ns.Add("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **MessageHeader.CreateHeader** method.

Use this overload method.
**CreateHeader(String, String, Object, XmlObjectSerializer)**

Parameters

**name** (String): The local name of the header XML element.

**ns** (String): The namespace URI of the header XML element.

**value** (Object): The content of the header to be created.

**serializer** (XmlObjectSerializer): An XmlObjectSerializer that is used to serialize the header.

This document is helpful to you:

[MessageHeader.CreateHeader Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageheader.createheader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-servicemodel-channels-messageheader-createheader(system-string-system-string-system-object-system-runtime-serialization-xmlobjectserializer))